# PHP halt function and send an email when array contains no elements

Tags: php, arrays, email, sendmail, matching

this is a PHP Question

i have a function

> function myfn () {
>
> ```
> where i get some data here and add result to an array
>
> $matches = array();
>
> preg_match_all('????????????', $searched, $matches);
>
> print_r($matches[1]);
>
> }
> ```

i need to halt or exit this function if the array contain no elements and send an email to xyz@mail.com

Appreciate your help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to exit function just do `return;`. But I'd just add some conditional blocks backed with `if()`. And to check if `$matches` array is empty do `count()`. So it could all look like this:

```
function myfn () {

   // where i get some data here and add result to an array
   $matches = array();
   preg_match_all('????????????', $searched, $matches);

   if( count($matches) > 0 ) {
     // there's something

     print_r($matches[1]);

   } else {

     // empty
     // send an email to xyz@mail.com

   }
}
```